# Grub not Showing 15.1, When I turn on the PC, it directly boots to Ubuntu 15.1 and shows no choice for Windows 7

Tags: 15.10

Already have Win 7 Installed. No OS Choice option after installing Ubuntu 15.10. 
Have only One 2TB hD
Have installed the grub and still the GRUB does not display to choose the OS

Comment: But your title says "grub not showing 15.1". Please edit your question to say there isn't an option for Windows in grub.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grub Customiser to simply configure your grub:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: When I turn on the PC, it directly boots to Ubuntu 15.1 and show no choice for Windows 7

Comment: @Vikram D - Please move that sentence to you question. There is a button to edit your question.

Comment: Thanks @Dev, please help me out with this. Need to use both OS. Struggling for last three days. Else Let me know the simplest way to uninstall Ubuntu to boot in Win 7

Answer (score 0):

Try Boot Repair it will reinstall grub and solves almost all issues add available loaders to grub menu entry

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

Comment: Great @ArUn, It worked

Comment: @VikramD if it resolved your issue mark soved ,it help others too :)

Comment: Okay, I am unable to find the Solved button. The issue is solved